# Skyrme model with both: vector & heavy mesons?

Tags: mesons

While the original [Skyrmion model](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/skyrmion) for effective hadrodynamics contained, of all mesons, only the pion, there are two well-studied directions in which it is successfully refined by incorporation of further mesons:

1) *light vector mesons* may be added following Adkins-Nappi ([references here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/skyrmion#ReferencesSkyrmeHadrodynamicsWithVectorMesons))

2) *heavy scalar mesons* may be added following Callan-Klebanov ([references here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/skyrmion#SkyrmeHadrodynamicsWithHeavyMesonsReferences))

It seems that all references that I have seen consider either 1) or 2), but not the combination of 1) and 2).

If anyone could point me to useful accounts, if any, with explicit discussion of Skyrme models incorporating both light vector mesons *and* heavy scalar mesons (say omega- and rho-mesons together with kaons and D-mesons), I would be grateful.